# tcolorbox: Vertically center title box

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

**I'd like to vertically center the title of a box on the top rule of the box.**

Unfortunatley I can't seem to find a way to **calculate the height of the title box dopending on the title text and margins**.

Is there a good way to do this?

Any advise as much appreciated :)

---

What I tried so far:

In the [Quick reference](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), all lengths that play a role are listed and looking at the code, I also got the values

- `/tcp/titlerule`: `\kvtcb@title@rule`
- `/tcb/toptitle`: `\kvtcb@toptitle`
- `/tcb/bottomtitle`: `\kvtcb@bottomtitle`
- `/tcb/boxsep`: `\kvtcb@boxsep`

Also the Title text seems to be stored in `\tcbtitletext`.

However, `\kvtcb@…` doesn't seem to act as lenght, i.e. `0.5\kvtcb…` gives an error, and I can only access `\tcbtitletext` *inside* the box env.

---

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift= -3.5mm, % What do I put here? I'd like to have something like:
%       yshift= -0.5\titleboxheight
    },
    top=4mm,
    coltitle=black,
    beforeafter skip=\baselineskip,
}

\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={A Box~--~#1}]%
    }{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{mybox}{This title box aligned correct}
        Some text.
    \end{mybox}

    \begin{mybox}{This title box is too low}
        Some text.
    \end{mybox}

    \begin{mybox}{\huge This title box is too high}
        Some text.
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can insert a `\strut` in the title box to make the titles in box 1 and 2 have the same height. What is the result you expect for box 3? The text is much higher, consequently the box has to be higher too.

Comment: That does indeed help a bit, thanks :) However, with `\strut`, the `yshift` is still depending on the fontsize: In box 3 I'd like the title box to be vertically centered on the top rule without manually changing the `yshift` (I added a line in the code to clarify the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if `yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2` solve your problem (its use is described in 10.2.2 Options for the Boxed Title Placement, `tcolorbox` documentation, page 159):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},  % <---
    top=4mm,
    coltitle=black,
    beforeafter skip=\baselineskip,
}
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={A Box~--~#1}]%
    }{
    \end{tcolorbox}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{This title box aligned correct}
    Some text.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{This title box is too low}
    Some text.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{\huge This title box is too high}
    Some text.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like I was just too stupid to read the docs correctly …

Comment: no, in such huge documentation is not simply find an information which you need ...